# How to Move Text Fields When Covered by Keyboard - Swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, xcode6

I have a problem, I have a view with 3 text fields, 2 of them are covered by the keyboard when I want to write something.

I found a code that moves the entire view up when the keyboard is shown but I only want to move the two text fields when they are pressed, while the rest of the view stays in place, is it possible?

The code I used -     http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-view-behind-keyboard-ios8-swift

Comment: But wouldn't you have overlapping issues?

Comment: I also want too blur the background so the app will focus on one text field at a time

Answer (score 0):

make use of the notification event, then you can make adjustments to your view.  The Notification also includes information about the size of the keyboard.

```
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
```